# Forming a HTTP response with strings

Tags: c++, rest, http

I am working on a HTTP server with boost, and I have some questions about forming the HTTP response, particularly the header.

Here's the code to assemble the GET response :

```
std::string h = statusCodes[200]; // The status code is already finished with a '\r\n'                                                                                  
std::string t = "Date: " + daytime_() + "\r\n";                                                                         
std::string s = "Server: Muffin 1.0\r\n";                                                                               

std::string content = search->second();                                                                                 
std::string type = "Content-Type: text/html\r\n";                                                                       
std::string length = "Content-Length: " + std::to_string(content.size()) + "\r\n";                                      
res = h + t + s + length + type + "\r\n" + content + "\r\n";
```

As they say on this [website](https://www.jmarshall.com/easy/http/), here's the header spec :

> The format of the request and response messages are similar, and
>   English-oriented. Both kinds of messages consist of:
>
> - an initial line, zero or more header lines,
> - a blank line (i.e. a CRLF by itself),
> - and an optional message body (e.g. a file, or query data, or query output).

But when I do a request on the server, only the date goes in the header, the rest is directly in the content

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK                 // Header
Date: Tue May 24 10:28:58 2016  // Header

Server: Muffin 1.0              // Content
Content-Length: 31
Content-Type: text/html

This is supposed to be an ID
```

I don't know what's wrong in that, it's the first time I'm dealing with HTTP response.

Thanks for your help

Comment: New line not always is CR LF. I don't remember but check in references.

Comment: @JacekCz I've checked multiple websites and they all say it's a CRLF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the bug.

My daytime function was returning a string with a newline character.

This was the original function, which uses the [depreciated ctime](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/ctime)

```
std::string
Response::daytime_()
{
    std::time_t now = std::time(0);
    return std::ctime(&now);
}
```

And now the new function with [strftime](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/strftime)

```
std::string
Response::daytime_()
{
    time_t rawtime;
    struct tm * timeinfo;
    char buffer[80];

    time (&rawtime);
    timeinfo = localtime(&rawtime);

    strftime(buffer,80,"%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y",timeinfo);
    std::string time(buffer);

    return time;
}
```

And the new way to form the responses, using just a '\n'

```
std::string res = "";

std::string h = statusCodes[200];
std::string t = "Date: " + daytime_() + "\r\n";
std::string s = "Server: Muffin 1.0\r\n";

std::string content = search->second();
std::string type = "Content-Type: text/html\r\n";
std::string length = "Content-Length: " + std::to_string(content.size()) + "\r\n";
res = h + t + s + length + type + "\n" + content + "\r\n";
```